# Make the code conditional jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, url, hash

OK I'm working on the new version of my website: http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise/

When you select a project by clicking on an image it dynamically loads the requested wordpress project page within the existing page and changes the url to include the hash so I get: http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise/#project

And if I give this direct url to people Wordpress automatically load the project page as if the user had clicked on the image within the page.

Everything is as I want it except for one thing my code make the project page ("#board") loads all the time even if there is no #project hash in the url so I would like to make the code conditional.

```
$(window).load(function(e){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    var post_slug = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    $("#board").load("http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise/ajax/",{slug:post_slug});
    $("#board").delay(1500).slideDown("slow");
});
```

http://url , http://url/ , http://url/# , http://url/#/ should not load the project board only http://url/#project or http://url/#whatever should

But I don't know how since I still new to jQuery and programming in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be like this:

```
$(window).load(function(e){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache:false});
    var post_slug = window.location.hash.substring(1);
    if(/^[a-zA-z0-9\-_]+$/.test(post_slug)){ //This conditions loading
       $("#board").load("http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise/ajax/",{slug:post_slug});
       $("#board").delay(1500).slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

We are asking if there's a string hash.

**EDIT**: I've updated the condition to use a regular expression to suite the needs you recently commented

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh great! Only one small problem it still loads the project board when I use the http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise/#/ url and it should not.

Comment: http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise/# / (the last slash is being cut by this forum... No space)

Comment: Which characters can you have? only numbers and letters?

Comment: It is only numbers, letters and dash (-) because they are created by Wordpress using the slug.

Comment: Now if I try the direct url it doesn't load the project board anymore http://themes.visualise.ca/visualise/#josie